# Redux toolkit query how to fetch individual items but display them all

Tags: rtk-query

I understood that RTK query does not follow a normalization approach but a document cache approach. I wonder though what is the best and simpler way to fetch individual items like these:

```
GET https://api.github.com/users/pastinepolenta
GET https://api.github.com/users/gaearon
```

and retain an array of those results so I can display them in a list.
Note how there is no "fetch all" API in this case as the github accounts I am fetching depend on what the user types.

Answer (score 0):

That array of ids/usernames in that case would be hand-managed global state in a slice (or local state of your parent component if you don't want to keep it for long).

Comment: thanks i understand how to set the ids, but then how to display all the users in one page based on those ids? meaning query RTK storage to combine the 2 info, the ids and the actual data

Comment: Have a child component that displays the value and map over all ids, passing the id as prop to that component/